# Browsing a SharePoint publishing page returns a 404 error message

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, publishing-site

I've changed the master page on a publish site collection. When I browsed back to the start site to check the new master page the browser just returned a 404 error, telling me that the page could not be found.

But when I open the site collection with the SharePoint Designer every thing seems to be ok and in its place. All pages are as expected in the page library. Within the Designer I could even open the pages for editing.

So does anyone has an idea why the browser cannot find and open the pages?

UPDTAE

To clarify my problem I should say, that also switching back to the default master page doesn't bring back the site. I still get a 404 response. So the problem shouldn't be directly related to my custom master page.

Comment: What type of master page did you switch to?

Comment: I switch to a custom one which was already used on other site without any problems.

Comment: Well, if the other one was a MOSS publishing site also, then it shouldn't be the master page. However, I would still do a side-by-side check of the contentplaceholders with an OOTB publishing master page :-)

Answer (score 0):

Approve the Master Page ?

Comment: Yes the master page was approved. As I already said, the master page was already used on other site collections of the web application without any problems. I only switched form the default master page to my custom one.